# ¿Cómo añadir un modelo EntityFramework a un proyecto de consola de .NET CORE en VS2017?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

tras mucho googlear y seguir tutoriales oficiales de Microsoft para .NET no he conseguido crear un modelo con EntityFramework. Existe mucha documentación pero pocos tutoriales, y menos aun cuando la base de datos a partir de la cual se quiere generar el modelo es MySql. Cuando vas a agregar un nuevo Item al proyecto y seleccionas "Datos" no aparece edmx Entity Data Model

Comment: Hola, echa un vistazo al [tour] y a [ask]. Tu pregunta, ahora mismo, es demasiado amplia, falta mucha información que podría ser útil. Te recomiendo mostrar lo que has hecho paso por paso para facilitar a los usuarios la información de lo que has hecho.

Comment: Qué es lo que tienes? como defines tus conexiones? cómo estás intentando hacer las migraciones? que tutoriales? has visto la documentación oficial? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Answer (score 0):

*"Tras mucho googlear y seguir tutoriales oficiales de Microsoft para .NET no he conseguido crear un modelo con EntityFramework. Existe mucha documentación pero pocos tutoriales, y menos aun cuando la base de datos a partir de la cual se quiere generar el modelo es MySql. **Cuando vas a agregar un nuevo Item al proyecto y seleccionas "Datos" no aparece edmx Entity Data Model**".*

Puede que no agregaras correctamente tu conexión. 
¿Tus entidades se crean sin problemas o mandan algún error? 
¿Te falta agregar algún plugin, etc.?

Hay mucha información en google. Por ejemplo aquí:
http://blog.enrique-zavaleta.com/como-crear-un-proyecto-mvc-con-entity-framework-a-partir-de-una-base-de-datos/

Comment: He añadido todas las dll de mysql agregadas. Plugins? no he leido que ninguno sea necesario. Si que he añadido el paquete nuget de EntityFramework para .Net Core.
Por otra parte la conexión a BBDD es correcta puesto que puedo ver las tablas en el explorador de servidores.
Ninguna entidad se crea.

Comment: En realidad no hay tanta información a cerca de lo que yo he preguntado. .NET CORE!! Fernando Carraco creo que no leiste con detenimiento mis tags ni mi comentario

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta Directa: No puedes**

Para usar **EF** en **.Net Core** debes usar entoncs **EF Core**
y EF Core no soporta y probablemente nunca soportará archivos edmx. porque entre otras cosas no estan alineados con las prácticas modernas de ORM.

Lo que puedes hacer es portar el edmx haciendo scaffold de las entidades para migrarlas a modelos de EF Core y de allí en más trabajar con EF Migrations.

Acá tienes la documentación oficial respecto a como hacerlo

[Portabilidad de un modelo basado en EDMX de EF6 a EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx)